# Log-in prompt on clicking input type submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, passwords

I have an asp.net page with a `<input type="submit">` for a button and vb codebehind.

```
<input runat="server" id="review" clientidmode="Static"
                        type="submit" value="review" name="submit" />
```

What code do I add so that I get create a required log-in prompt pop-up box asking for a username and password. I also want to make sure that when the user types the password that the password field will not show the specific characters.

Comment: I'm just curious; can you not use TextBox with RequiredFieldValidator?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET I think you may be after the `<asp:Login />` component. Personally I prefer to avoid using ASP.NET components due to all the gratuitous HTML they generate and prefer to code all this manually but for a beginner it may be the quickest choice to get you setup.

See the [first example in this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx):

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" 
            UserNameLabelText="E-mail address:" 
            OnLoggingIn="OnLoggingIn"
            OnLoginError="OnLoginError" >
        </asp:Login>

    </form>
```

Your code-behind text will look as follows:

```
Sub OnLoggingIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs)
    If Not IsValidUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) Then
        Login1.InstructionText = "Authentication Failed."
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        Login1.InstructionText = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub
```

And on the main page you can create a popup box using [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) as follows:

```
 <a href="javascript:;" 
     onclick="window.open('myloginpage.aspx', 'login', 'width=600,height=400,scrollbars=no')"/>
```

Alternatively if you want to use an input button for this the code is the same but using `INPUT` instead of an `A` tag.

```
 <input runat="server" id="review" clientidmode="Static"
              type="button" value="review" name="submit"
              OnClientClick="window.open('myloginpage.aspx', 'login', 'width=600,height=400,scrollbars=no')" />
```

Bear in mind most browsers nowadays include **popup blockers** that might make it difficult for your users to actually reach the login page.

Comment: For some reason, I don't get a prompt, I just get an error message. Will this onclientclick still work if I have a codebehind method that handles the button click as well.                         Private Sub review_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles preview.ServerClick
        pnlForm.Visible = False

        CreateRequest(ConnectToServiceReturnSID())
        pnlReview.Visible = True
        pnlConfirmation.Visible = False
    End Sub

Comment: Yep, since you specify `runat=server`, the `onclick` event gets handled by .NET, and then re-writes the `onclientclick` event as `onclick` to serve it out to javascript on the browser. Makes no sense but then its Micro$oft we talking about so I dont expect it to.

Comment: So what would be the vb equivalent of calling the login prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your design (collecting the login details on submit) creates several significant hurdles for you to overcome:

- How do you cancel the login prompt if the user name and password fails?
- How do you collect and pass the the entered user name and password back to the original page?
- If the user forgets their credentials and needs to reset them or needs to register for the first time, how does the information get back to the submit flow correctly?

It might be much easier to protect entry to your site through a user name and password than to try and collect this information during the submit process.

Microsoft has an excellent walkthrough on the exact steps that you need to implement this process in this MSDN article: [How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx).

However, if this is not appropriate for your situation, then I would suggest something along the lines of this [jQuery Login Dialog](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-login-dialog/).